# mariadb v15.1 do not installs socket / Centos 7

Tags: mysql, centos7, mariadb

Installed CentOS 7 fresh

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)

yum -y install mariadb-server mariadb

# mysql -V
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.52-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

/usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation


Enter current password for root (enter for none):
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
Enter current password for root (enter for none):

 mysqladmin password newpassword

mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' exists!
```

checking /var/lib/mysql/

```
la /var/lib/mysql/

# ls /var/lib/mysql/
aria_log.00000001  aria_log_control  ibdata1  ib_logfile0  ib_logfile1  mysql  performance_schema  test
```

any idea why that should happening ?
and how to fix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you got was:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

[2 is ENOENT](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/uapi/asm-generic/errno-base.h), or No such file or directory. This means the socket doesn't exist. And the cause of that is that MariaDB is not running. You need to start MariaDB before running `mysql_secure_installation`.

```
systemctl start mariadb
```

Comment: such a minor mistake , cheers